# error in iostream.h in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, iostream

Added header files as

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

in the program body used some iostream functions such as cout,cin etc.

but when running the program getting the error message as

> ```
> InitializeBuildStatus:
> 1>  Creating "Debug\precompiled.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
> 1>ClCompile:
> 1>  me.cpp
> 1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdlib.h(353): error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs
> 1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\gl\glut.h(146) : see declaration of 'exit'
> 1>
> 1>Build FAILED.
> ```

Comment: This looks like incompatible Visual Studio and Windows SDK versions.

Comment: but it works well in some other problems.
I think need any other commands to add?

Comment: glut.h has not been included with the Windows SDK for a long time.  You copied it there, clearly it is not a very compatible version.  You'll have to fix it.

Comment: yes. I copied glut.h file to windows SDK but still having the error.

Comment: @bushra Oh! Why would you do that? Of course that's not going to work.